# Vertically/Horizontally centering text over an img-container

Tags: jquery, html, css, text

I'm still learning html and css so please be gentle but I'm having trouble centering my text over each individual image container (http://jsbin.com/uwolat/1/edit). I've tried top and height at 50% but it doesn't constrain to the specific parent container. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` `ಠ_ಠ`

Comment: ŠimeVidas rather than the face give him feedback. He stated he's new, get off your high horse. user2252219, what SimeVidas is saying is take a look at optimising your HTML for HTML5 - here is a link to get your started: http://www.html5rocks.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/7bc7j/1/

Give a class `.imgTitle` to all of your title `p` tag. No need separate id for all of them.

The following scripts will align all of them vertically/horizontally center, for any width of text, long or short.

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.img-container').each(function() {
        // Get a reference to the image.    
        var img = $(this).find('img');
        var p = $(this).find('.imgTitle');
        
        // center the title
        $(this).children('p.imgTitle').css({
           'top':((img.height() - p.height())/2) - 13,
           'left':(img.width() - p.width())/2
        });
        
        // Hide by default.
        img.hide();
        
        $(this).hover(function() {
            img.stop().fadeIn(50);
        }, function() {
            img.stop().fadeOut(1300);
        });
    
    });
});
```

## HTML

```
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="http://wallpaper-fun.ophibian.com/wallpapers/wallpaper_08.jpg" alt="a" width="100%" height="200" />   
  <p class="imgTitle">Pure Waves</p>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting

position:relative;
text-align:center;

for your text

Comment: position:relative will let you position your element inside the div that contains it

Answer (score 0):

The trick is in `line-height`

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uwolat/4/edit)**</kbd>

**Don't repeat your self,** remove all the unneeded ID's from your `p` elements.
Give a class to your `<p>` elements: `<p class="description">Bla bla bla</p>`

**CSS:**

```
.img-container
{
  /*display: block;*/  /* DIV is already BLOCK level element*/
  /*float: inline;*/   /* Back to school ;) */
  margin:0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 200px;
  line-height:185px; /* PLAY HERE */
  background: #e5e5e5;
  border-bottom:1px solid #444; /* added just for demo */

  text-align:center; /* to align inner P text */
}

.description
{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;        
    /*height:200px;*/  /* if needed? */
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys! Really appreciated your help. Not sure if this forum uses rep or anything but thumbs up. :)