# Vertical Centering some Text over an Image with Dynamic Height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

For whatever reason I am really beating myself up with this...  No doubt because of the lack of support for a real "proper" way of vertically centering anything.

### The Goal:

Is to have a set of four images, each inside their own responsive columns.  Each image has a white overlay, that when hovered reveals more of the image, as well as a title for each of the 4 images that is horizontally and vertically centered inside the image.

I could easily achieve this if I set specific width/heights and stuck the image inside CSS rather than the HTML. For SEO reasons I want the image to be present in the HTML.

Additionally because of the responsive nature, the images must scale to 100% of the width of the column they reside in.  Consequently, because the width scales, the height scales as well.

So the first issue is getting the "caption" as I am calling it in my classes, to appear over the top of the image.  Easily done with a simple `position: absolute;` as well as `top: 0;` and `left: 0;` on the caption and `position: relative;` on the container.

The big problem and second issue, is vertically centering the "Gallery 1" text over the top of the image.  I have to use the `position: absolute;` bit as I mentioned above just to get the text over-top of the image.  From there I can't manage to get a `display: table;` solution to work, nor a -50% margin solution to work.

Here is a **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zh4G6/)**

My **HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-640-480-8.jpg" />
    <div class="caption">
        <a href="#">Gallery 1</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?  I would like to stay at least IE8 supported, and I am using selectivizr already, so pseudo-classes don't bother me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, I wasn't sure about what you mean exactly. But as you mentioned:

> The issue is centering the text `Gallery 1` vertically over the top of the image. Centering it horizontally is easy with a simple `text-align` but centering it vertically is what is eluding me.

Here is my attempt to align the text vertically over the image. Actually the concept comes from **[this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height/18516474#18516474)** of a similar topic on SO:

```css
.container { position: relative; }

.container img {
    vertical-align: bottom; /* Remove the gap at the bottom of inline image */
    max-width: 100%;
}

.caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font: 0/0 a; /* Remove the gap between inline(-block) elements */
}

.caption:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;    
}

.caption a {
    font: 16px/1 Arial, sans-serif; /* Reset the font property */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1% 0; /* Added a relative padding for the demo */
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/zh4G6/4/embedded/result/)**.

This relies on CSS2.1 and it will definitely work on IE8+ (excluding `rgba()`).

Comment: This is perfect.  I modified it slightly to achieve my visual needs - http://jsfiddle.net/zh4G6/5/

thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, this may work for you:

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zh4G6/1/)**

If you need the image to scale when hovered over, then simply adding a `:hover` on the container and changing it's width should work.

CSS:

```
.container {
    // existing styles
    -webkit-transition: all .2s; // needs prefixes for other browsers.
}

.container:hover {
    width: 500px;
}
```

The only issue is that `transition` has no support for IE9 or earlier. So you'd need to go a JS route if that is an issue.

Comment: I apologize, I did not make myself clear.  I will edit the above to make it more obvious.  The issue is centering the text "Gallery 1" vertically over the top of the image.  Centering it horizontally is easy with a simple text-align: but centering it vertically is what is eluding me.