# Adding text above an image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add text over an image using css. I am using bootstrap. I have not to use background image.

```
 <div id="myCarousal" class="carousal slide">
            <div class="carousal-inner"> 
            <div class="item active"> 
              <img src="img/cr1.jpg">
                <div class="container active">
                  <div class="carousal-caption"> 
                  <h1>  Quiz </h1>
                  <p> Want to be part of it..</p>

                  <p> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Sign Up Today</a></p>

                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

The CSS is as follows..

```
.carousel-caption{
    z-index:10;
    position: absolute; 
   top: 200px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img{
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    /*left: 0;*/
    min-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.carousel-inner > .item{
    height: 500px;   
}
```

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: have you tried putting your text before ``img`` tag?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/

Comment: Also take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708945/how-to-position-text-over-an-image-in-css

Comment: @HashemQolami I need to add at the bottom..and I went through both the sites..

Comment: @knitevision It went to the top of the image..

Comment: Here is an answer I wrote few months ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582774/add-text-overlay-to-panel-and-image-with-zurb-foundation/21584335#21584335 you might find it helpful.

Comment: I think this is the result of writing mistake :) carousel &Carousal

Answer (score 0):

Try adding z-indexes for each element. Just in case, we're adding a z-index for everything inside .carousel-caption just to avoid any chance you have some z-index somewhere

```
.carousel-inner .item img{
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    /*left: 0;*/
    min-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index:0;
}
.carousel-caption{
    z-index:1;
    position: absolute; 
   top: 200px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
}
.carousel-caption *{
    z-index:1000;
    position: relative;
}
```